# Set-EXOMailboxFolderPermissions (is it a thing?)

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I am newly navigating the M365 / Powershell modules environment.  I am trying to use all Exchange Online PowerShell V2 commands (and Powershell 7) where applicable, just to be future facing.

While settings calendar permissions in v2: I noticed there's a `Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission` which replaces `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`, however I do not see a `Set-EXOMailboxFolderPermission`.
Should I just continue using `Set-MailboxFolderPermission` inline with `Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission` / is that the optimal command tie-in?

Thanks!

PS: Apologies-  my reputation is not high enough to do a tag for: "exchange-online-powershell-v2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer would be - it depends on how you manage your environment, if it's Hybrid or Online only and other specific settings. For Hybrid you will need to use both most likely (depending on the task).

If you have MFA enabled and connecting to Exchange Online directly, you can only connect using EXO cmdlets as per Microsoft Documentation.

So I would go with MS Advice on each specific task.

> Note: In Exchange Online PowerShell, we recommend that you use the
> Get-EXOMailboxFolderPermission cmdlet instead of this cmdlet. For more
> information, see Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps

Details on MFA:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps